# Dynamically changing font size based on stepper value

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uifont, uistepper

I'd greatly appreciate any insight you could share on the below issues/questions.

**Intended Use:**
I'd like to dynamically change font size based on a UIstepper. In the action triggered after editing the stepper, I try to change the font of a UILabel, cleverly named myLabel.

**Code Snippet**

```
@IBAction func changeFont(sender: UIStepper) {
        var stepval = sender.value;
        sizeLabel.text = NSString(format: "%.1f", sender.value); //change size label to display the size
        myLabel.font = UIFont(name: "System", size: CGFloat(stepval)) ; //change myLabel to desired font size
    }
```

**Issue/Questions**:

1. Did I correctly cast the double to a CGFloat in the UIFont (using the CGFloat constructor)
2. When I run this, the sizeLabel updates with the numerical font size I'd like myLabel to be, but myLabel does not change in font size. Do I need to force update a view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. CGFloat() successfully creates a CGFloat with that double value
2. To change the font, use UIFont.systemFontOfSize(CGFloat())